# AJAX reload page with POST

Tags: javascript, ajax

Can anybody tell me how to refresh the current page with JavaScript, having a POST variable modified or added?

To be clear, I want to set some POST variables prior to reloading the page.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity, based on your comments under answers.

Comment: @StuperUser I know I can make it with GET variables by window.location.href, but I would like to achieve this by a post variable, and don't know how. I think with XMLHttpRequest is not a very good choice.

Comment: As @Pranav Hosangadi's said, if you're reloading the whole page, why are considering XHR rather than a normal HTTP Request? The whole point of XHR is that you don't have to reload the entire page.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

By using jquery ajax you can reload your page

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "packtypeAdd.php",
    data: infoPO,
    success: function() {   
        location.reload();  
    }
});
```

Comment: This depends on jQuery, since the OP has only tagged this with JavaScript, make sure you refer to jQuery in your answer. It's also useful posting a link to the jQuery API docs if you refer to a jQuery function. You can also use `post()` instead of the longhand `ajax()` for this.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to refresh the entire page, it makes no sense to use AJAX. Use normal Javascript to post the form element in that page. Make sure the form submits to the same page, or that the form submits to a page which then redirects back to that page

Javascript to be used (always in myForm.php):

```
function submitform()
{
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}
```

---

Suppose your form is on myForm.php:
Method 1:

```
<form action="./myForm.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    ...
</form>
```

---

Method 2:

myForm.php:

```
<form action="./myFormActor.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    ...
</form>
```

myFormActor.php:

```
<?php
    //all code here, no output
    header("Location: ./myForm.php");
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I already saw this possibility, but Im thinking if is possible to write something like XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("name", "value");

Comment: If you want to add an additionnal content in you post, one way is to add a new hidden form element to the form before submitting it.

Answer (score 5):

Reload the current document:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function reloadPage()
 {
   window.location.reload()
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: yes, but I need to set some post variables before. Is it possible?

Comment: Why u want through POST method

Comment: You can also this <script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
 setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>

Comment: I'm just thinking about this. I know it can be very well achieved by setting the GET variables, but I just want to know if is possible to set POST variables.

Answer (score 1):

There's [another way](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object) with `post` instead of `ajax`

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Got trouble making it too but it will be better if you don`t use ajax.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
SelectOnChange = document.querySelector("#payment"); //for <select> didn`t include it...
SelectOnChange.onchange = function(){
    SelectedValue = SelectOnChange.value;
    document.querySelector("#payment_schedule_date").value = SelectedValue;
    document.getElementById('paymentform').submit(); //<form>
}
});
</script>
```

In HTML just put input with hidden and use .submit() to submit using form.

```
<form name="paymentform" id="paymentform" action="#" method="post">
<input hidden name="payment_schedule_date" id="payment_schedule_date" value="">
```