# POST data to the same page (not through URL)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

Am a newbie, a hardcore one.

I am in a need of reloading page with passing variables; so when the page is reloaded it would already have those variables before initializing some of the elements (as u can guess, those variables will be used there).

I need this because I am working with an old videoplayer, which can't be reset on-the-fly, the whole page has to be reloaded to re-initialize it with new params.

Also these variables cannot be passed through url, because they are too long.

I would be glad to see any help and to answer clarifying questions as well.
Thanks!

UPD1: There's no real need to delve into specifics of my code thus not posting it; Just imagine a simple page with a textfield and a button, where user enters a string, presses the button, then the page reloads getting that string into a global variable.

UPD2: Found this code on a related page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "packtypeAdd.php",
    data: infoPO,
    success: function() {   
        location.reload();  
    }
});
```

That is how I post the data and reload. But how do I get it after reload then? How is this data accessible?

Comment: Post your code please...

Comment: updated question, hope it clarifies my case

Comment: @BruteForce, always post some kind of code with every question. It is a standard of how this site works, so anybody can come in and immediately tell what is going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX reload page with POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268294/ajax-reload-page-with-post)

Comment: @Naltroc I definitely would, but in this case there's quite nothing to post. Shall I create a dummy page with a textfield and a button? Would it help somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about making a simple HTML form with attributes action="" and method="post" like:

```
<form action="" method="post"> <!-- in action specify where you want the content to be sent, the method speaks about his self -->
<input type="[type]" name="[name]"> <!-- in the name attribute define the name with which you can call the data in PHP via $_POST[name] -->
...some input fields...
...submit btn probably...
</form
```

> **Note:** clicking the submit button automatically send the information to the page and redirects you to it. If you leave action empty like above it will redirect you to the same page (refresh it) and receive the data from the form.

Also if you don't want to use a form you can simply set cookies with PHP. For example:

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expireDate, $path(e.g "/");
```

And then just take information from the cookie with:

```
$_COOKIE[$name]
```

> **Note:** in order to make cookies work, you need to refresh the page, so they can be set!

Comment: Cookie idea is interesting to know, but here I need to do it without cookies.
Could you, please, give me a more detailed answer (or a link probably?) on how such html form would work in my case?

Comment: Also for more detailed help/examples/information contact me on ickomcdevill@gmail.com (so we don't spam the comments) i hope i helped you. :)

Comment: Okay, simple enough :) I'll ask further questions via e-mail. Thx :)