# ajax post request loading page and showing parameters in url

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<script>    
    function insert_record(){

            alert($("#myform").serialize());

            $.ajax({

                type:"POST",
                url:"data.php",
                data:$("#myform").serialize(),
                success:function(x){

                }
                //end of success function

            }); 

    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the question? Please explain in detail what is it that you are trying to do and what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to give us more to work with, expand on the question, the problem, and the things you've tried.

Ill give it a shot based on assumptions tho..

I am going to assume you have an HTML form that has method set to POST. And you are (trying to) bypass the actual sending of the data (submit) to a javascript function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit

It is expected for this to reload the page

[AJAX reload page with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268294/ajax-reload-page-with-post)

Atleast, I am doing another asumption that the origin of the reload is not from the AJAX call but from the orignal #myform submit.

As to why the parameters show up in the URL ? Might want to double check if the method is set to POST.