# How to wordpress reload only sidebar by ID auto every X (sec) without page load

Tags: wordpress, reload, sidebar

I try many searches without luck, so I write it here.

How can i in wordpress reload only the sidebar (content) by ID auto every X (sec) without page load?

I.e.

```html
<div id="secondary">Here the Sidebar content and widgets to be auto reloaded every x min.</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

you can do this with ajax request 
look at this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "packtypeAdd.php",
    data: infoPO,
    success: function() {   
        location.reload();  
    }
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8268361/8941806

Comment: This have not to do with what i need. I dont need "url" and i need reload by ID with time

Comment: that url is specify which file will run and that file is which file is that you can reload by id with time. you need to write a code for refreshing content for your query and after that, you must use ajax for run that code without reload page. without ajax, you can't do that.

Comment: ok. in my case wich php file sould i include? the sidebar.php?

Comment: no, of course. php file that includes the code which is refresh your content. when you call it with ajax, you can refresh your content without reload page. please, search.

Comment: Without file, only a div content by id or class cant working?