# How to send POST request upon dropdown selection in Flask without Submit button?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have the following dropdown form in my html page that is used to order the results of a page. I would like to send a post request to my Flask app when a user clicks an option instead of the user having to select an option, then click the button "Order" to send the post request.

How can I accomplish this?

HTML Code:

```
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <select class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" name="order-by" id="order" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <option value="Default" {% if order_by==None %} selected {% endif %}>Default</option>
                <option value="Recent" {% if order_by =="Recent" %} selected {% endif %}>Recent</option>
                <option value="Alphabetically (A-Z)" {% if order_by=="Alphabetically (A-Z)" %} selected {% endif %}>Alphabetically (A-Z)</option>
                <option value="Alphabetically (Z-A)" {% if order_by =="Alphabetically (Z-A)" %} selected {% endif %}>Reverse Alphabetically (Z-A)</option>
                <option value="Follower Count (High-Low)" {% if order_by =="Follower Count (High-Low)" %} selected {% endif %}>Follower Count (High to Low)</option>
                <option value="Follower Count (Low-High)" {% if order_by =="Follower Count (Low-High)" %} selected {% endif %}>Follower Count (Low to High)</option>
                <option value="Random" {% if order_by =="Random" %} selected {% endif %}>Random</option>
            </select>
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Order">
        </form>
```

Flask Route:

```py
@app.route("/results", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def results():
    order_by = None
    results = get_results(order_by)
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_by = request.form["order-by"]
        curators = get_results(order_by)
    return render_template("results.html", title="Results", results=results, order_by=order_by)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with js. Add onchange event to select element and reload page with POST on this function.

You can check below pages:

- For on change: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp
- For reload with post: [AJAX reload page with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268294/ajax-reload-page-with-post)